# Activity class does not exist?

Tags: java, android, xml, manifest, android-resources

I am trying to make a game that switches the activity whenever the user clicks a button. I am trying to use the Application class to use a variable throughout all of my activities, this is the variable for the current time in milliseconds when the app starts.

[image]

Then, in the game over screen I want to find the current time again, and then subtract currentTime from the new current time. This should give me the amount of time the user has been playing the game. After finding this value; I simply want to display it on the screen. The problem is, I am getting the following error:

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=  [android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]     cmp=com.example.username.buttonsmasher/.Main_Menu }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class  {com.example.username.buttonsmasher/com.example.username.buttonsmasher.Main_Menu} does not exist.
```

**Here is my Main_Menu onCreate activity, where I set the currentTimeMillis as the variable CurrentTime, which I get from the myCurrentTime class:**

[image]

**Here is the gameOver screen where I display the total time spent on the app:**

[image]

**Here is the android manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.username.buttonsmasher" >


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Main_Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Left_Up"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_left__up" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Left_Center"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_left__center" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Left_Down"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_left__down" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Center_Up"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_center__up" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Center_Center"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_center__center" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Center_Down"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_center__down" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Right_Up"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_right__up" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Right_Center"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_right__center" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Right_Down"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_right__down" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GameOver"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_game_over" >
    </activity>
</application>

<application>android:name=".myCurrentTime"</application>

</manifest>
```

Please help me as to why this error is happening. The reason I only posted certain methods of the app is because I know the issue is with the time. The app was running fine untill today, when I tried to add the time display. I really appreciate your help, and I have been trying to solve this issue for over 2 hours now! Thank you so much, and if you need any more information, feel free to let me know. **Any** feedback is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Show your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: @DanielNugent Thanks for the quick reply! I have posted the Manifest file!

Comment: Is your code running at all? Remove all of your logic for time calculations and run the empty project. I'm not sure about performing variable calculations outside of the scope of the activity life cycle like that.

Comment: @Daniel Nugent Yes, I have thoroughly researched the topic. I think the issue may be that I need the extend Activity in all the classes that are using the myCurrentTime.java class. The thing is, I can't extend more than one class, which is why i'm stuck. Do you have any suggestions? My code was running before all of my time calculations; which I added today. About the variable calculations, I am not sure that if I change the variable "currentTime" in a class other than the manifest, will the entire variable value change to that? Then can I access that changed variable in another class?

Comment: @Daniel Nugent The thing with the variable is that I can only test whether I can change it and access the changed variable from another activity once this error goes away. Thank's so much for your feedback, I really appreciate getting help from an expert like you!

Comment: I have had similar problems with "global variables". They give errors if the app tries to use them after a "long" time. My practical solution to this is to store that kind of data to preferences file and read it from there when needed.

Comment: @WilliamGreendale How would I access it from the preferences file? Also...where is the preferences file? Thanks so much for all the help!

Comment: @Rich http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I didn't see your second Application tag. I don't think you can do that :)

Place the name property inside the first application tag and remove the second one.

Comment: Hmmm...I get a long error after this. I will post it here.

Comment: Do you know what the problem could be? Thank you!

Comment: Did you replace your name with 'username' in that gist? Otherwise your package setup could be wrong. For some reason it can't find myCurrentTime as an Application in your project. Try cleaning / rebuilding as well.

Comment: I only replaced my name with username when I posted it on stack overflow, otherwise, my name is in android studio. I will try to clean and rebuild my project, and get back to you. THanks!

Comment: That means the gist indicates the app is trying to find com.example.**username**.buttonsmasher.myCurrentTime, which it can't so it cannot be cast to an application. Or the file does exist, but it's an incorrect a duplicate of com.example.XXXX.buttonsmasher.myCurrentTime, or you application tag is still not quite correct.

Comment: It could be my application tag. I will post my new manifest. Thanks.

Comment: Yup I guess I wasn't clear :) Line 60 needs to be inside the tag constructor, between lines 6 and 7 for example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93843/discussion-between-rich-and-daniel-wilson).